# How to put variables in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm learning vue and i have small problem.

I've created code, which receive some informations from webserwer (via socket) and this code works fine.

But i would like to do very simple thing - display info as variable in HTML and i have problem with it.

My code is:

```
    export default {
  components: {
    BCard,
    BButton,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      connection: null,
      json: {
        cmd: 'start',
        width: 1024,
        height: 800,
        url: 'https://www.google.com',
        token: '',
        service_id: 1,
        thumbnail_width: 100,
        thumbnail_height: 100,
      },
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log('Starting Connection to WebSocket')
    this.connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/')
    // this.connection = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org')
    this.connection.onopen = function (event) {
      console.log(event)
      console.log('Success')
    }
    this.connection.onmessage = webSocketOnMSG
  },
  methods: {
    sendMessage(message) {
      console.log(this.connection)
      console.log(message)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(message))
      const dat = this.connection.send(JSON.stringify(message))
      console.log('TT', dat)
    },
    drawItem() {
      const img = document.createElement('img')
      const canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId')
      img.src = 'http://image...'
      img.onload = function (a) {
        const h = a.target.height
        const w = a.target.width
        const c = canvas.getContext('2d')
        canvas.width = w
        canvas.height = h
        c.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
        document.getElementById('draw-image-test').appendChild(canvas)
      }
    },
    webSocketOnMSG(msg) {
      console.log(msg)
    },
  },
}
```

and i would like to add code like this:

```
data: {
xposition: 'xpos',
yposition: 'ypos'
}
```

but when i'm adding it to created earlier `data()` i have error, so this doesn't work:

```
data() {
xposition: 'xpos',
yposition: 'ypos',
        return {...}
}
```

where should i add code to replace variables {{xposition}} and {{yposition}} in HMTL?

Comment: In Vue, you declare an object from which you have access in the template and in all methods and lifecycle hooks. So, return an object `{ a: 123, b: { x: 321 } }` in data and you can access e.g. `a` in a method with `this.a`. You can also access it in the template with `{{ a }}` or `{{ b.x }}`. So, just overwrite the relevant property of that object in the method and it will automatically reflect to the template.

Answer (score 1):

You must put your new variables inside your returned object in the data function, alongside your 'json' variable. You need to declare them first as empty values, and then add the proper values in your API call callback

```js
data() {
  return {
    xposition: '',
    yposition: '',
    ...
  }
}
```

```js
    webSocketOnMSG(msg) {
      // this will change your component's xposition property
      this.xposition = msg.propertyYouWantToAccess
    },
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28838698)

Comment: @Regolith You are right, I didn't properly understand the author's question. I edited my response to give a proper answer!